# Wait ultil ajax .html successfull load object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i wait until .html done loading before firing other query ?

here is my code

a href

```
<a class='smsnoti' href='http://someurl.com'>Notify</a>
```

javascript

```
$('.smsnoti').bind('click', function(e) { 
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $("div#container").html('<object data="'+url+'">'); // i want to wait untill this load complete
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the browser from following the link
    $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<center><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">SMS Sent!</div></img></center>').fadeOut(4000); //want to show this after the .html complete
});
```

Answer (score 1):

may be you could try with `.promise().done()` method chaining this way:

```
$('.smsnoti').bind('click', function (e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $("div#container").html('<object data="' + url + '">').promise().done(function () {
        $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<center><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">SMS Sent!</div></img></center>').fadeOut(4000);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: can't get it. as we have `e.preventDefault()` so the default behavior of anchor is now disabled.

Comment: ok . the url actually an api link that will send sms to phone . I want to load the link without open the page

Comment: then you can use a iframe with width/height of 0 otherwise i don't think this would be done without openining the page.